# In php, how do I sort an array of paths based on a specific (in this case the last) path-fragment?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, path, fragment

I have an array like so:

```
[0] => /home/user/public_html/things/1 - First thing/
[1] => /home/user/public_html/things/3 - Third thing/
[2] => /home/user/public_html/things/2 - Second thing/
```

What's the straightforward way to sort this array so the `'things'` go 1, 2, 3?

I've used `natsort()` on just the last path-fragment but it's not proving straightforward to use... I chopped the rest of the path off, sorted, then put it back on but that's ugly and it can change in the mean time so I'm hoping for a better way than that.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure there's several ways to approach this :)

Comment: `usort()` + `basename()`

Comment: In the example you give, sorting by the the whole path or just the last part will give the same result.  So why don't you just sort the paths as they are? Or if this is not your actual case, can you give a better example in your question?

Comment: That exact thought occurred to me a moment or two ago.... Why am I not just sorting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question as it stands (*sort an array of paths based on a specific path-fragment*), I thought of a function that would allow you to specify the fragment you want the paths to be sorted on.

As the paths in the example only differ in their last part, the above is not very interesting when applied on that example. So I will use a slightly different list:

```
$paths = [
    '/home/user/public_html/things/sub/1',
    '/home/user/public_html/things/3',
    '/home/admin/public_html/things/2'
];

function build_sorter($part) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($part) {
        return strnatcmp(
            implode("/", array_slice(explode("/", $a), $part)),
            implode("/", array_slice(explode("/", $b), $part))
        );
    };
}

// sort by second part in paths:
usort($paths, build_sorter(2));
print_r ($paths);
```

The output generated has put the "admin" folder first:

```
   Array (
     [0] => /home/admin/public_html/things/2
     [1] => /home/user/public_html/things/3
     [2] => /home/user/public_html/things/sub/1
   )
```

Sorting by the last part would go like this:

```
usort($paths, build_sorter(-1));
print_r ($paths);
```

Output:

```
   Array (
     [0] => /home/user/public_html/things/sub/1
     [1] => /home/admin/public_html/things/2
     [2] => /home/user/public_html/things/3
   )
```

So the argument you pass to `builder_sort` is the offset (positive from left, negative from right) of the part of the paths you want to base your sort on.

Comment: This is interesting, appears very flexible. I've been trying explode > do something > implode... There must be a reason why I didn't simply sort the array of paths, the example you cover is probably it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Applying **[asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)** function can do it.

```
$p = [
    '/home/user/public_html/things/1',
    '/home/user/public_html/things/3',
    '/home/user/public_html/things/2'
];

asort($p);

print_r($p);
```

Comment: You don't sort the array by the last part of the path. You sort the array by the entire path, which is not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

I'm this approach:

1. find the 1st integer in the path
2. define the found int value as the key for the current path in a new array
3. sort the new array with ksort()

```
    $paths = [
        '/home/user/public_html/things/1 - First thing/',
        '/home/user/public_html/things/3 - Third thing/',
        '/home/user/public_html/things/2 - Second thing/'
    ];

    $matches = [];
    $sorted_paths = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (preg_match('/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
            $sorted_paths[$matches[1]] = $path;
        }
    }

    ksort($sorted_paths);
    print_r($sorted_paths);
```

As the result, I've got something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => /home/user/public_html/things/1 - First thing/
    [2] => /home/user/public_html/things/2 - Second thing/
    [3] => /home/user/public_html/things/3 - Third thing/
)
```

Comment: Use the integer as key for new array - perfect

Comment: (although I find "1st integer in the path" a bit indiscriminate)

Comment: You're right! Think it is not a very flexible solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what i comprehend you want to sort your array results by the number after the thingy folder.

```
<?php 
$Directories = array('/home/user/public_html/things/1', '/home/user/public_html/things/3', '/home/user/public_html/things/2');

$SortedNums = array();

foreach ( $Directories as $Dir )
{
    $Nums = explode("/", $Dir);

    foreach ( $Nums as $Num )
    {
        if ( is_numeric($Num) )
        {
            array_push($SortedNums, $Num);
        }   
    }
}

sort($SortedNums);

$ArrayLength=count($SortedNums);
for($x=0;$x<$ArrayLength;$x++)
{
   echo $SortedNums[$x];
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Produces the following output:

1
2
3